# How do I convert data from html table into array of object using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

It's well known, that 'array of objects' format of data storage is well suitable for data persisting. I'd be extremely grateful if a JavaScript guru helps me with finding the answer to how do I read this HTML-table with vanilla JavaScript and transport data from it into the following array of objects.

I have produced tons of code, mostly comparing two arrays of objects. Unfortunately, I didn't come even closer to a solution.

The table to scrape data from:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Toronto</td>
      <td>Montreal</td>
      <td>Vancouver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>Chicago</td>
       <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Washington</td>
       <td>Detroit</td>
       <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Expected outcome to be like so:

```
 [
 {"country":"Canada","city":"Toronto"},
 {"country":"Canada","city":"Montreal"},
 {"country":"Canada","city":"Vancouver"},
 {"country":"USA","city":"New York"},
 {"country":"USA","city":"Chicago"},
 {"country":"USA","city":"Boston"},
 {"country":"USA","city":"Washington"},
 {"country":"USA","city":"Detroit"},
 {"country":"USA","city":"Los Angeles"}
 ]
```

The code is valid, unlike the approach:

```
let theResult = [];
    arrayOfCountriesAndCitiesObjects.forEach((item, iIndex) => {
        arrayOfCitiesObjects.forEach((elem, eIndex) => {
            if(item.city !== elem.city && item.iIndex < elem.eIndex) theResult.push(copy(elem, item)); 
        });
    });
    function copy(firstObj) {
      for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        let arg = arguments[i];
        for (let key in arg) {
          firstObj[key] = arg[key];
        }
      }
      return firstObj;
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to change the markup for you? i.e. adding css classes to that table rows?

Comment: Absolutely, actually, I have simplified the table, the true one is full of css' classes around both countries and cities.

Comment: does @Nina Scholz's answer fit your needs? Otherwise i can provide one using some class-selector logic

Comment: @MaksymDudyk : If you happen to deal with much larger data and performance  considerations do matter, you might want to check out my answer below as it gives you certain [advantage](https://jsperf.com/parse-city-country-table/1) in that regard, while `for` loop solution can be much faster on a small input table, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` to loop thru each `tr`. Find the `td` on each `tr`, If there is only 1, store the text on `currentCountry` variable. If more than one, push the object to the result variable.

```js
var currentCountry = "";
var result = [];

var tr = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  var td = tr[i].querySelectorAll('td');

  if (td.length === 1) currentCountry = td[0].innerHTML;
  else if (td.length > 1) {
    for (var a = 0; a < td.length; a++) {
      result.push({country: currentCountry,city: td[a].innerHTML});
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Toronto</td>
      <td>Montreal</td>
      <td>Vancouver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>Chicago</td>
      <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Washington</td>
      <td>Detroit</td>
      <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and what happens if there appears an entry with a country where only a single city is given? according to your logic this city would be identified as a country

Comment: OMG. I missed that there is no jQuery. I convert the jQuery code to vanilla. I guess we let OP decide if that scenario is possible.

Comment: I am trying to scrape data from the page overloaded with tags and css. Your solution seems to be very easy to readjust to my case. Thank you, Eddie.

Comment: Happy to hear about that :)

Answer (score 3):

You could store the value of `colSpan === 3` as country and push all other values as city to the result set.

This works with plain Javascript without any libraries.

```js
var result = [],
    country = '';

document
    .querySelectorAll('table td')
    .forEach(td => {
        if (td.colSpan === 3) {
            country = td.innerHTML;
            return;
        }
        result.push({ country, city: td.innerHTML.trim() });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Toronto</td>
      <td>Montreal</td>
      <td>Vancouver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>Chicago</td>
       <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Washington</td>
       <td>Detroit</td>
       <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks clean and elegant, Nina! I will try out your solution in real life. Thank you very much, so far.

Comment: Nina, let's suppose, I need to address each last 'td' to make an extra key/value pair record in object. Taking Eddie's code, I'd just add _var lastCell = td[2].innerHTML_ inside the second loop. How would I do that in your code?

Comment: then you need a row and iterate the row. it would be easier, if you add the problem to the question, or better ask a new question, because this question is already answered as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign all `<tr>` which contain country names a special class. Then use `querySelectorAll` and use `forEach` loop.

```js
const tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

const arr = []
let count = '';

tr.forEach(x => {
  if(x.classList.contains('head')){
    count = x.children[0].innerHTML
  }
  else{
    let child = [...x.querySelectorAll('td')]
    arr.push(...child.map(a => ({country:count,city:a.innerHTML})))
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="head">
      <td  colspan="3">Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Toronto</td>
      <td>Montreal</td>
      <td>Vancouver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="head" >
      <td colspan="3">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>Chicago</td>
       <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Washington</td>
       <td>Detroit</td>
       <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @MaksymDudyk Fixed. This was because I was pushing result of `map()` with out `...`

Comment: Maheer, your code has resulted in five container arrays, instead of one. But the idea with using _classList.contains_ as a check-mark is cool!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var country = null, result = [];
var tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr td"));
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
 let item = tds[i];
 if (item.getAttribute("colspan") == "3") {
  country = item.innerText;
  continue;
 }
 
 result.push({ country: country, city: item.innerText });
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Toronto</td>
   <td>Montreal</td>
   <td>Vancouver</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">USA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>New York</td>
   <td>Chicago</td>
   <td>Boston</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Washington</td>
   <td>Detroit</td>
   <td>Los Angeles</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, Marcelo, I'll try out your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce

```
 const items = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody td')

 const results = [...items].reduce((allItems, item)=>{
   if(item.getAttribute('colspan') === '3'){
     allItems['country'] = item.textContent
     return allItems
   }
   allItems.push({country: allItems['country'],city:item.textContent})
   return allItems
 },[])
```

Comment: Dennis, your script isn't working correctly, spitting out extra "country:USA"; The problem, I guess, is here: 
_allItems['country'] = item.textContent_

Comment: Oh yeah!!! I was lazy to create the country variable outside the reduce loop but @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg answer below does that. I chose this because all loops skip named indices in the array and they are not included in the length computation of the array

Answer (score 1):

Not that elegant, but to me slightly more comprehensive (while being [**the fastest**](https://jsperf.com/parse-city-country-table/1) for larger input data samples)  `reduce()` solution:

```js
const result = [...document.getElementsByTagName('td')].reduce((res, item) => (item.getAttribute('colspan') == 3 ? res.country = item.textContent : res.obj = [...(res.obj || []), {country: res.country, city: item.textContent}], res), {}).obj;

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Toronto</td>
      <td>Montreal</td>
      <td>Vancouver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>Chicago</td>
       <td>Boston</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Washington</td>
       <td>Detroit</td>
       <td>Los Angeles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Super! Thank you!